# Building a Large .npz file Efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, google-colaboratory, data-management

I have a dataset of about 20,000 images that I'm going to use to train a CNN. The images are on my Google Drive. I'm trying to find out how to load the images onto Colab so I dont have to query each image for every epoch on google drive.

My current approach is to save the images into a .npz file, so I can load it into Colaboratory once and avoid having to read google drive thousands of time.

However, I'm running into memory limitations as I build the list `arr` below. Memory limitations on Colabs 25 GB of RAM. I tried building a .npz file with just 1000 images, and the colab session still crashes due to RAM. Each image is on average around 192 KB. I'm not sure if the issue is exclusive to the list of numpy arrays, or maybe PIL isn't the best choice for loading images in this situation.

Any thoughts on where the problem may be?

Edit: After more experimenting, an .npz file of just 50 images is 640 MB!
I guess my question at this point should be; which method is better for importing my data into Colab?

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# x is a list of file locations for all images
arr = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    img = np.array(Image.open(x[ii]))
    # append array to list
    arr.append(img)
X_array = np.asarray(arr)
np.savez('/content/drive/My Drive/', X_array)
```

Comment: Note, if you want to compress the archive, you need to use `numpy.savez_compressed`. `numpy.savez` doesn't actually do compression.

Comment: Oh I did not know you can do that. I will give that a try...

Comment: `savez` (the `compressed` version doesn't change memory use), creates a `zip` archive, with one `.npy` file for each array.  You are trying to create one large array and save that. So the `npz` format does do anything special for you.  But it sounds like you hit memory problems in the loop on images, even before you try to make `X_array`.  You haven't even gotten to the `savez`.

Comment: It might be worth checking the size (`nbytes`) of one `img` array.  Also what's it's `dtype`.  Often the array of equivalent of an image takes up much more memory (especially if the images are in some compressed format).  Loading all images into memory is not an option.

Comment: Correction, `npz` does **nothing** extra for you.  In any case you haven't got there; 'efficiency' isn't the issue.  Memory is.  Regardless of the dtype and image size, if you try to load too many images into memory you run out of space.  ML packages like `tensorflow` have a `batch` mechanism to get around such memory limits.